# Web crawling for multiple websites with different structures

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, jsoup

I want to do a web crawl on multiple websites with different structures to find a specific data. However, I have some keywords to help me find what I want. To be more clear, I want to extract a list of profs names from a university's website and loop it on a given list of universities. The keywords, here, can be the word "Professor" or "Prof" or "Dr" before their names and an email after their names. However, it's a bit challenging to deal with different html structures that each website has.

What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends.

**Option 1:** If "multiple websites" means a handful, maybe up to ten, you could try building a separate scraper for each of them.

Advantage: you get exact results and you get all results.

Disadvantage: whenever a site changes the scraper breaks and needs adjustments and this will be too much work when there are 100s of sites or more.

**Option 2:** If "multiple websites" means really many websites, building a scraper for each site is most probably too expensive. In this case the only other option I can think of is to build a generic crawler that crawls all sites and then run NLP algorithms on the results to extract the data you need.

I gave on overview how such an NLP based processing pipeline would look like in a recent, somewhat similar question: [How to crawl thousands of pages using scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543450/how-to-crawl-thousands-of-pages-using-scrapy/43558953#43558953)

Advantage: once it is running and fine tuned, it doesn't matter whether there are 100s or 1000s of sites to process and it is quite robust when sites change.

Disadvantages: getting this up and running is more difficult than writing a scraper and you will never get 100% of the results neither will they be 100% accurate.

*added in 2020/04*:
**Option 3:** In some markets you'll see that a handful of specialized content management systems or site templates are very common and following the pareto rule / 80/20 rule you often can cover 60-80% of all sites by implementing just a handful of specialized scrapers.

Advantage: you get exact results and you get all results and can still cover the majority of 100s or 1000s of seemingly different websites.

Disadvantage: this works only when there enough commonalities among most websites which happens usually if a small number of specialized (content management) systems are widespread in this "market"

Comment: The option 2 is exactly what I want. May I ask where can I find a sample of such a package? Or at least, where should I begin from? I am no programming expert, and I bet you have guessed it from my question. So, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well unfortunately there is no ready made package for such systems as such systems are quite complex and have to be adjusted and trained for each domain. When I'm building such systems it's usually taking several person-weeks stretched over 2-3 months. If you have basic understanding of programming and want to learn how to do this a good starting point is learning the basics of NLP (natural language processing). There are plenty of good books on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have actually found this [http://www.nltk.org/book/] and really excited to see what can I do with it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.